# Cmdlet Runs Much Faster in ISE than Console

Tags: powershell

I have developed a Powershell Cmdlet, and a script that drives it. I have found that the functionality of the Cmdlet runs very quickly in Powershell ISE, and also via a wrapper EXE called from the command line (say 2 minutes). However if I call the script in CMD via `powershell.exe -File` the same operation takes 6-7 minutes.

The script basically loads some DLLs via `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile`, loads a type full of configuration info via `Add-Type`, then calls the custom Cmdlet (once- not in a loop). The Cmdlet functionality involves lots of database access, network storage access, and processing. I cannot post source code of any kind.

I have found that in both ISE and the command line, the ApartmentState is STA and the Host version (Major, Minor, Build, Revision) is (3, 0, -1, -1).

My question is: what further checks are available to identify the reason for this difference in execution time?

Comment: The ISE is an implementation of powershell that simply does not identically mimmic the console. Generally speaking you shouldn't run anything in the ISE that you want to represent the way a script will work in the console.

Comment: Does the cmdlet emit any output? A lot? A little? What version of Windows are you observing this on?

Comment: You can write an entry to a logfile every x steps to pinpoint which "block" of code is causing the delay.

Comment: Reduce your code to smaller chunks to monitor time. I don't think SO will be able to debug this one for you without seeing anything nor having your exact environment. You could have profiles that only work in one of those environments. -NoProfile might be a simple check

Comment: I can't quickly find the citation, but PowerShell scripts pasted into the console are not compiled/optimized by the .Net JIT, unless they contain functions. Saved scripts are JIT compiled. This can make a massive difference to runtime, so I wonder if `powershell.exe -file` behaves like pasting the content, rather than running a saved file. If your script is not already like this, try wrapping `function DoWork { #code }; DoWork` around it and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: what further checks are available to identify the reason for this difference in execution time?

Have you considered the already available debugging options?

You could pack a couple of `WriteVerbose()` statements into your command at strategic places:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Diagnostics;

class DoDatabaseStuffCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    private Stopwatch stopWatch;

    //
    // ... parameter definitions go here
    //

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        // load whatever you need 
        this.WriteVerbose(String.Format("Loading dependencies: {0}s", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        this.WriteVerbose(String.Format("Processing item at {0}s", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
        // process input 
        this.WriteVerbose(String.Format("Done processing item at {0}s", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        this.WriteVerbose(String.Format("Starting cleanup at {0}s", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
        // clean up
        this.WriteVerbose(String.Format("Done cleaning up at {0}s", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
        stopWatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

In the calling script you can use `Write-Verbose` instead:

```
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.StopWatch]::StartNew()
foreach($assembly in $assemblies){
    Add-Type -Path $assembly
    Write-Verbose "Done loading $assembly after $($stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)s"
}
# and so on
```

Execute with `-Verbose` to see what's going on:

```
powershell.exe -File "\path\to\script.ps1" -Verbose
```